# Better approaches to use lombok builder + Switch statement for cleaner code

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I am trying to build an object based on a type of an input parameter. The problem with the below code is that it becomes more verbose as I add more functions to it. Is there any way to simplify this using a Hashmap or are there any other lombok annotations which can help in this mapping between a string and a Lombok builder object ?

```
        switch (functionType) {
            case "ABS":
                function = Abs.builder().argument(args).build();
                break;
            case "SUM":
                function = Sum.builder().argument(args).build();
                break;
            case "IF":
                function = IfThen.builder().argument(args).build();
                break;
            case "IFNA":
                function = IfNa.builder().argument(args).build();
                break;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need essentially is a factory class. On top of that, I do not think there is a need for you to use lombok for this case. Assuming that your objects only require the `args` parameter to be passed in, have a look at the following:

```java
public class FunctionFactory {

    private static final Map<String, Function<List<String>, BaseFunction>> SUPPLIER_MAP = Map.of(
        "ABS", Abs::new,
        "SUM", Sum::new,
        "IF", IfThen::new,
        "IFNA", IfNa::new
    );

    public static BaseFunction getImplementation(String functionType, List<String> args) {
        return SUPPLIER_MAP
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entrySet -> entrySet.getKey().equals(functionType))
            .findAny()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(function -> function.apply(args))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(String.format("Cannot find suitable implementation for type %s", functionType)));
    }

}
```

What this does essentially is to create a static map of mappings, mapping your `functionType` (which should have been an `Enum` to a constructor of each concrete implementation of the abstract `BaseFunction` class. Having that place, you need only to call `getImplementation` in order to iterate through the map, test the keys against the input value and retrieve the appropriate constructor.

I hope this is something that could help you in order to get under way refactoring your code.

Comment: I doubt whether the stream was required since you are using the supplier map. Instead you could have done as : `Optional.ofNullable(SUPPLIER_MAP.get(functionType)).map(function -> function.apply(args)).orElseThrow(/*exceptionSupplier*/);`